# How to give Python admin permission to run a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a file in a Python script:

```
import os
os.system("C:\Games\Toribash-4.8\toribash.exe")
open ("c:\Games\Toribash-4.8")
```

But I recieve the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/Python Projects/Python Summative.py", line 5, in <module>
    open ("c:\Games\Toribash-4.8")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\Games\\Toribash-4.8'
```

Comment: With `open ("c:\Games\Toribash-4.8")` -- you are trying to open a directory, and hence the error. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`c:\Games\Toribash-4.8` is not an executable, and so it cannot be run.

In the more general case, this is something you need to fix with Windows file permissions, not in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the **permissions** for the file, which is something not typically done with python. Instead, try to log in as an administrator, or use a `runas`.